# How to deploy Node.js as service in Android?

Tags: android, node.js, androidjs

I currently have an app in NodeJS that execute some functions regularly without user input.

I would like to make it available as an app in Android. I see AndroidJS as an option however they don't support service/background app which is a requirement.

What would be the next best option? I'm willing to rewrite the code in a different language if necessary (ideally not) but most important for me is to not spend too much time to package it as an app. AndroidJS seemed really easy, too bad you can deploy a service app.
I simply want to package my code as APK, and get it installed as a service.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.  Android is not meant to run things in the background.  You can't have a permanent background service in Android, the OS will kill any background process for resources eventually.  Even foreground services would eventually be killed.  Also, an app must have at least one Activity, an app cannot launch a service until an Activity in it has been run.

If you stuck in a do nothing launcher Activity, you could rewrite it in native and use JobScheduler or WorkManager to get a recurrent action performed-  maybe.  Depending on how frequently you need that to occur.  The minimum repeat interval for those things is 15 minutes, but they're the only long term reliable methods of running.

Comment: Thank you. There are services that run in the background after the user has started them, this is what I meant. May be killed if needed but it is possible to have background tasks running (IFTTT app for example). That is what I meant, to be able to run an app in the background with NodeJS.

Comment: @igorjrr IFTTT doesn't run in the background.  It works with push messaging.  That's a totally different way of doing things.  You can use push messaging with RN, but it requires you to use FCM or similar whitelisted from power management system level service.  Basically, when a message comes in the app is started in the background.  It isn't running in the background normally.  It then is stopped as soon as that single message is processed